# Possible to grab a text from a online .txt file via bash?

Tags: macos, bash, text

Is it possible to grab text from a online text file via grep/cat/awk or someting else? (in bash)

The way i currently do this is i download the text file to the drive and grep/cat into the file for it's text.

curl -o "$TMPDIR"/"text.txt" http://www.example.com/text.txt

cat/grep "$TMPDIR"/text.txt

rm -rf "$TMPDIR"/"text.txt"

Is one of the text grabbers (or another one) capable enough to grab something from a text file on the internet?
This would get rid of the whole downloadfile-readfile-deletefile process and just replace it with one command, speeding up things considerably if you have a lot of those strings.

I couldn't find anything via the man pages or googling around, maybe you guys know something.

Comment: ..on a side note: I hope you´ve not developed a habit of simply using `rm -rf` whenever you want to delete something (in cases like this, where a simple `rm` would be enough), this could get potentially dangerous in the future.

Comment: Why are you doing a forced recursive removal of a single temporary file? Simply do `rm "$TMPDIR/text.txt"`. Note that you don't need the extra set of quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `curl -o - http://www.example.com/text.txt | grep "something"`.

`-o -` tells curl that it "downloads to stdout", other utils such as wget, lynx and links also have corresponding functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You might try netcat - this is exactly what it was made for.

Comment: netcat is too low-level. You'd have to construct the HTTP headers yourself -- curl is a lot better for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could at least pipe your commands to avoid manually creating a temporary file:

```
curl … | cat/grep …
```